# Produce as many lines in SQL thant an integer in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in this form:

```
    TABLE_ID   NUMBER

    0A         3
    4B         2
    ...
```

Is it possible to make a request that gives:

```
    0A 1
    0A 2
    0A 3
    4B 1
    4B 2
```

or better (formatted)

```
    0A001
    0A002
    0A003
    4B001
    4B002
    ...
```

Thus for every single line in the table, repeating as many lines in the result as the integer and numbering them.

Comment: It's possible, some reputation hunter will probably give you the solution, but you should be smart and avoid doing that in SQL.

Comment: Show your efforts with code which you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table t (id varchar(10), num int);

insert into t values('0A',3);
insert into t values('4B',2);

create table nums (n int);

insert into nums values(1);
insert into nums values(2);
insert into nums values(3);
insert into nums values(4);
insert into nums values(5);
insert into nums values(6);

select concat(t.id,'00',nums.n)
from nums join t 
on nums.n <= t.num;
```

You can try this. It is better you use a loop to construct the nums table based on the maximum number you have in your table. Also, you should decide on the pattern for 2 digit numbers, if they should still contain 2 `0`'s or 1 and similarly for 3,4,..n digit numbers. You should use a `case` statement in that scenario based on the length of the number.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21aa9/1

Comment: This suggestion is simple and works for me. By the way, in place of using a `case` to switch between adding 1 or more `0`'s, there is this trick: `concat(t.id, right(concat('000', nums.n), 3))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
declare @top int = 1000

declare @values table (Code varchar(10), Number int)
insert into @values (Code, Number) values ('0A', 3)
insert into @values (Code, Number) values ('4B', 2)

declare @Numbers table (ID int)

while @top > 0
    begin
        insert into @Numbers (ID) values (@top)
        set @top = @top - 1
    end


select 
    Code + right('000' + cast(ID as varchar(10)), 3)
from
    @values V
    inner join @Numbers N on V.Number >= N.ID
order by
    Code, 
    ID
```

Ooops! Misleading title... I noticed after posting the answer that this is about `mysql` and my answer is using `MSSQL`. Anyway, maybe you can use this somehow ...